# Lavacharts 'ready' event not being fired

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, google-visualization

I am using [Lavacharts](http://lavacharts.com/) (powered by Google Chart API) to render charts in my Laravel application.

I want to be able to handle the 'ready' event, which should be triggered, once the rendered chart is ready for interaction. According to [this](http://lavacharts.com/#javascript), all I have to do is define a Javascript callback function, before any php render method, and then pass the name of the function while configuring the chart in PHP.

After following the above steps, my callback function is never called, and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The Javascript function is defined in the  section of the page:

```
function chartReady (event, chart) {

    alert('Chart is ready!');

}
```

This is how I define the chart in PHP:

```
\Lava::PieChart('ExpensePieChart', $dataTable, [
    'events' => [
        'ready' => 'chartReady'
    ],
    'title' => 'Expense distribution on categories',
    'height' => 500,
    'legend' => [
        'position' => 'right'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Are you getting any console errors or anything?

Comment: No, the console is clear. I also tried handling other events such as 'click' or 'select', but still no luck.

Comment: "Define a javascript function within your page, before the any php render method.". Have you tried to include this function inside `<head>`?

Comment: Can you add some more code? Such as where the javascript function is defined in your web page and where the PHP code is being run.

Comment: Is the chart being rendered?